# Change Text Link to Button

Tags: button, shopify

I am building a new site on the Empire Shopify theme and I am trying to change a text link into a button on the dynamic featured product section.

So changing this:
[Featured product with text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lg70a.png)

Into this:

[Call to action the button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/85yqC.jpg)

Can anyone advise on the best way to do this please?

Here is the section code:

```
{% assign product = all_products[section.settings.product] %}
{% assign onboarding = false %}

{% if product.empty? %}
  {% assign onboarding = true %}
{% endif %}

<script
  type="application/json"
  data-section-type="dynamic-featured-product"
  data-section-id="{{ section.id }}"
  data-section-data
>
  {
    "settings": {
      "cart_redirection": {{ settings.enable_cart_redirection | json }},
      "money_format": {{ shop.money_format | strip_html | json }},
      "gallery_video_autoplay": {{ section.settings.gallery_video_autoplay | json }},
      "gallery_video_looping": {{ section.settings.gallery_video_looping | json }},
      "gallery_thumbnail_position": {{ section.settings.gallery_thumbnail_position | json }},
      "gallery_hover_zoom": {{ section.settings.gallery_hover_zoom | json }},
      "gallery_click_to_zoom": "disabled",
      "swatches_enable": {{ settings.swatches_enable | json }},
      "sold_out_options": {{ settings.sold_out_options | json }},
      "select_first_available_variant": {{ settings.select_first_available_variant | json }}
    },
    "context": {
      "select_variant": {{ 'product.general.select_variant' | t | json }},
      "product_available": {{ 'product.buttons.add_to_cart' | t | json }},
      "product_sold_out": {{ 'product.buttons.sold_out' | t | json }},
      "product_unavailable": {{ 'product.buttons.unavailable' | t | json }},
      "product_preorder": {{ 'product.buttons.pre_order' | t | json }}
    },
    "product": {% unless onboarding %}{{ product | json }}{% else %}false{% endunless} %}
  }
</script>

<script type="application/pxs-animation-mapping+json">
  {
    "blocks": [".product-main"],
    "elements": [
      ".product-details",
      "[data-product-form-area]"
    ]
  }
</script>

<section class="featured-product--container home-section--content" data-product-wrapper>
  <div class="featured-product--inner">
    {%
      render 'product',
      product: product,
      is_product_modal: false,
      is_featured_product: true,
      onboarding: onboarding,
      show_dynamic_checkout_button: settings.show_dynamic_checkout_button,
      select_first_available_variant: settings.select_first_available_variant,
      gallery_aspect_ratio: section.settings.gallery_aspect_ratio,
      gallery_thumbnail_position: section.settings.gallery_thumbnail_position,
      gallery_image_crop: section.settings.gallery_image_crop,
      gallery_click_to_zoom: 'disabled',
      gallery_hover_zoom: section.settings.gallery_hover_zoom
    %}
  </div>
</section>

{% schema %}
{
  "name": "t:sections.featured_product.name",
  "class": "featured-product--section",
  "settings": [
    {
      "id": "product",
      "type": "product",
      "label": "t:sections.featured_product.product.label"
    },
    {
      "type": "header",
      "content": "t:sections.product.header_1.content"
    },
    {
      "type": "paragraph",
      "content": "t:sections.product.paragraph_1.content"
    },
    {
      "type": "select",
      "id": "gallery_aspect_ratio",
      "label": "t:sections.product.gallery_aspect_ratio.label",
      "options": [
        {
          "value": "natural",
          "label": "t:sections.product.gallery_aspect_ratio.option_1"
        },
        {
          "value": "short",
          "label": "t:sections.product.gallery_aspect_ratio.option_2"
        },
        {
          "value": "square",
          "label": "t:sections.product.gallery_aspect_ratio.option_3"
        },
        {
          "value": "tall",
          "label": "t:sections.product.gallery_aspect_ratio.option_4"
        }
      ],
      "default": "natural"
    },
    {
      "type": "checkbox",
      "id": "gallery_image_crop",
      "label": "t:sections.product.gallery_image_crop.label",
      "info": "t:sections.product.gallery_image_crop.info",
      "default": false
    },
    {
      "id": "gallery_thumbnail_position",
      "type": "select",
      "label": "t:sections.product.gallery_thumbnail_position.label",
      "info": "t:sections.product.gallery_thumbnail_position.info",
      "options": [
        {
          "value": "below",
          "label": "t:sections.product.gallery_thumbnail_position.option_1"
        },
        {
          "value": "left",
          "label": "t:sections.product.gallery_thumbnail_position.option_2"
        }
      ],
      "default": "below"
    },
    {
      "type": "checkbox",
      "id": "gallery_video_autoplay",
      "label": "t:sections.product.gallery_video_autoplay.label",
      "default": true
    },
    {
      "type": "checkbox",
      "id": "gallery_video_looping",
      "label": "t:sections.product.gallery_video_looping.label",
      "default": true
    },
    {
      "id": "gallery_hover_zoom",
      "type": "select",
      "label": "t:sections.product.gallery_hover_zoom.label",
      "options": [
        {
          "value": "disabled",
          "label": "t:sections.product.gallery_hover_zoom.option_1"
        },
        {
          "value": "replace",
          "label": "t:sections.product.gallery_hover_zoom.option_2"
        }
      ],
      "info": "t:sections.product.gallery_hover_zoom.info",
      "default": "disabled"
    },
    {
      "type": "paragraph",
      "content": "t:sections.product.paragraph_2.content"
    }
  ],
  "blocks": [
    {
      "type": "@app"
    },
    {
      "type": "collapsible-tab",
      "name": "t:sections.product.blocks.collapsible_tab.name",
      "settings": [
        {
          "type": "text",
          "id": "collapsible_tab_heading",
          "label": "t:sections.product.blocks.collapsible_tab.collapsible_tab_heading.label",
          "default": "Collapsible tab"
        },
        {
          "type": "richtext",
          "id": "collapsible_tab_text",
          "label": "t:sections.product.blocks.collapsible_tab.collapsible_tab_text.label",
          "default": "<p>Use this text to share information about your product.</p>"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "type": "custom-liquid",
      "name": "t:sections.product.blocks.custom_liquid.name",
      "limit": 1,
      "settings": [
        {
          "type": "liquid",
          "id": "custom_liquid",
          "label": "t:sections.product.blocks.custom_liquid.custom_liquid.label",
          "info": "t:sections.product.blocks.custom_liquid.custom_liquid.info"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "type": "description",
      "name": "t:sections.product.blocks.description.name",
      "limit": 1
    },
    {
      "type": "form",
      "name": "t:sections.product.blocks.form.name",
      "limit": 1,
      "settings": [
        {
          "type": "paragraph",
          "content": "t:sections.product.blocks.form.paragraph_1.content"
        },
        {
          "type": "header",
          "content": "t:sections.product.blocks.form.header_1.content"
        },
        {
          "type": "checkbox",
          "id": "enable_local_pickup",
          "label": "t:sections.product.blocks.form.enable_local_pickup.label",
          "info": "t:sections.product.blocks.form.enable_local_pickup.info",
          "default": true
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "type": "key_details",
      "name": "t:sections.product.blocks.key_details.name",
      "settings": [
        {
          "type": "select",
          "id": "icon",
          "label": "t:sections.product.blocks.key_details.icon.label",
          "options": [
            {
              "value": "none",
              "label": "t:sections.product.blocks.key_details.icon.option_1"
            },
            {
              "value": "icon-award-trophy",
              "label": "t:sections.product.blocks.key_details.icon.option_2"
            },
            {
              "value": "icon-car",
              "label": "t:sections.product.blocks.key_details.icon.option_3"
            },
            {
              "value": "icon-cell-phone",
              "label": "t:sections.product.blocks.key_details.icon.option_4"
            },
            {
              "value": "icon-chat",
              "label": "t:sections.product.blocks.key_details.icon.option_5"
            },
            {
              "value": "icon-chat-alternate",
              "label": "t:sections.product.blocks.key_details.icon.option_6"
            },
            {
              "value": "icon-credit-card",
              "label": "t:sections.product.blocks.key_details.icon.option_7"
            },
            {
              "value": "icon-delivery",
              "label": "t:sections.product.blocks.key_details.icon.option_8"
            },
            {
              "value": "icon-delivery-cart",
              "label": "t:sections.product.blocks.key_details.icon.option_9"
            },
            {
              "value": "icon-delivery-door",
              "label": "t:sections.product.blocks.key_details.icon.option_10"
            },
            {
              "value": "icon-delivery-package",
              "label": "t:sections.product.blocks.key_details.icon.option_11"
            },
            {
              "value": "icon-email",
              "label": "t:sections.product.blocks.key_details.icon.option_12"
            },
            {
              "value": "icon-envelope",
              "label": "t:sections.product.blocks.key_details.icon.option_13"
            },
            {
              "value": "icon-gift-card",
              "label": "t:sections.product.blocks.key_details.icon.option_14"
            },
            {
              "value": "icon-heart",
              "label": "t:sections.product.blocks.key_details.icon.option_15"
            },
            {
              "value": "icon-information",
              "label": "t:sections.product.blocks.key_details.icon.option_16"
            },
            {
              "value": "icon-label-tag",
              "label": "t:sections.product.blocks.key_details.icon.option_17"
            },
            {
              "value": "icon-lock",
              "label": "t:sections.product.blocks.key_details.icon.option_18"
            },
            {
              "value": "icon-number-14",
              "label": "t:sections.product.blocks.key_details.icon.option_19"
            },
            {
              "value": "icon-number-24",
              "label": "t:sections.product.blocks.key_details.icon.option_20"
            },
            {
              "value": "icon-number-30",
              "label": "t:sections.product.blocks.key_details.icon.option_21"
            },
            {
              "value": "icon-people",
              "label": "t:sections.product.blocks.key_details.icon.option_22"
            },
            {
              "value": "icon-pin",
              "label": "t:sections.product.blocks.key_details.icon.option_23"
            },
            {
              "value": "icon-question-mark",
              "label": "t:sections.product.blocks.key_details.icon.option_24"
            },
            {
              "value": "icon-rating-five-star",
              "label": "t:sections.product.blocks.key_details.icon.option_25"
            },
            {
              "value": "icon-rating-star",
              "label": "t:sections.product.blocks.key_details.icon.option_26"
            },
            {
              "value": "icon-smile",
              "label": "t:sections.product.blocks.key_details.icon.option_27"
            },
            {
              "value": "icon-store",
              "label": "t:sections.product.blocks.key_details.icon.option_28"
            },
            {
              "value": "icon-tape-measure",
              "label": "t:sections.product.blocks.key_details.icon.option_29"
            },
            {
              "value": "icon-thumbs-up",
              "label": "t:sections.product.blocks.key_details.icon.option_30"
            },
            {
              "value": "icon-transfer",
              "label": "t:sections.product.blocks.key_details.icon.option_31"
            }
          ],
          "default": "icon-delivery-package"
        },
        {
          "type": "image_picker",
          "id": "image",
          "label": "t:sections.product.blocks.key_details.image.label",
          "info": "t:sections.product.blocks.key_details.image.info"
        },
        {
          "type": "text",
          "id": "title",
          "label": "t:sections.product.blocks.key_details.title.label",
          "default": "Delivery time"
        },
        {
          "type": "richtext",
          "id": "text",
          "label": "t:sections.product.blocks.key_details.text.label",
          "default": "<p>Use this text to share information about your product and policies with your customers.</p>"
        },
        {
          "type": "color",
          "id": "text_color",
          "label": "t:sections.product.blocks.key_details.text_color.label",
          "default": "#1D1D1D"
        },
        {
          "type": "color",
          "id": "icon_color",
          "label": "t:sections.product.blocks.key_details.icon_color.label",
          "default": "#1D1D1D"
        },
        {
          "type": "color",
          "id": "background_color",
          "label": "t:sections.product.blocks.key_details.background_color.label",
          "default": "#f5f3ed"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "type": "inventory_status",
      "name": "t:sections.product.blocks.inventory_status.name",
      "limit": 1,
      "settings": [
        {
          "type": "radio",
          "id": "inventory_display",
          "label": "t:sections.product.blocks.inventory_status.inventory_display.label",
          "info": "t:sections.product.blocks.inventory_status.inventory_display.info",
          "options": [
            {
              "value": "all_products",
              "label": "t:sections.product.blocks.inventory_status.inventory_display.option_1"
            },
            {
              "value": "low_stock_threshold",
              "label": "t:sections.product.blocks.inventory_status.inventory_display.option_2"
            },
            {
              "value": "low_stock_only",
              "label": "t:sections.product.blocks.inventory_status.inventory_display.option_3"
            },
            {
              "value": "hidden",
              "label": "t:sections.product.blocks.inventory_status.inventory_display.option_4"
            }
          ],
          "default": "hidden"
        },
        {
          "type": "checkbox",
          "id": "inventory_transfer_notice",
          "label": "t:sections.product.blocks.inventory_status.inventory_transfer_notice.label",
          "info": "t:sections.product.blocks.inventory_status.inventory_transfer_notice.info",
          "default": true
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "type": "price",
      "name": "t:sections.product.blocks.price.name",
      "limit": 1
    },
    {
      "type": "rating",
      "name": "t:sections.product.blocks.product_rating.name",
      "limit": 1,
      "settings": [
        {
          "type": "paragraph",
          "content": "t:sections.product.blocks.product_rating.paragraph_1.content"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "type": "share",
      "name": "t:sections.product.blocks.share.name",
      "limit": 1
    },
    {
      "type": "tabs",
      "name": "t:sections.product.blocks.tabs.name",
      "limit": 1,
      "settings": [
        {
          "type": "checkbox",
          "id": "show_product_description",
          "label": "t:sections.product.blocks.tabs.show_product_description.label",
          "default": false
        },
        {
          "type": "checkbox",
          "id": "show_tabs_below_product_gallery",
          "label": "t:sections.product.blocks.tabs.show_tabs_below_product_gallery.label",
          "info": "t:sections.product.blocks.tabs.show_tabs_below_product_gallery.info",
          "default": false
        },
        {
          "type": "header",
          "content": "t:sections.product.blocks.tabs.header_1.content"
        },
        {
          "type": "text",
          "id": "tab_heading_1",
          "label": "t:sections.product.blocks.tabs.tab_heading_1.label",
          "default": "Tab 1"
        },
        {
          "type": "richtext",
          "id": "tab_text_1",
          "label": "t:sections.product.blocks.tabs.tab_text_1.label",
          "default": "<p>Use this text to share information about your product.</p>"
        },
        {
          "type": "header",
          "content": "t:sections.product.blocks.tabs.header_2.content"
        },
        {
          "type": "text",
          "id": "tab_heading_2",
          "label": "t:sections.product.blocks.tabs.tab_heading_2.label",
          "default": "Tab 2"
        },
        {
          "type": "richtext",
          "id": "tab_text_2",
          "label": "t:sections.product.blocks.tabs.tab_text_2.label",
          "default": "<p>Use this text to share information about your product.</p>"
        },
        {
          "type": "header",
          "content": "t:sections.product.blocks.tabs.header_3.content"
        },
        {
          "type": "text",
          "id": "tab_heading_3",
          "label": "t:sections.product.blocks.tabs.tab_heading_3.label",
          "default": "Tab 3"
        },
        {
          "type": "richtext",
          "id": "tab_text_3",
          "label": "t:sections.product.blocks.tabs.tab_text_3.label",
          "default": "<p>Use this text to share information about your product.</p>"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "type": "sku",
      "name": "t:sections.product.blocks.sku.name",
      "limit": 1
    },
    {
      "type": "text",
      "name": "t:sections.product.blocks.text.name",
      "settings": [
        {
          "type": "richtext",
          "id": "text",
          "label": "t:sections.product.blocks.text.text.label",
          "default": "<p>Text block</p>"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "type": "title",
      "name": "t:sections.product.blocks.title.name",
      "limit": 1
    },
    {
      "type": "vendor",
      "name": "t:sections.product.blocks.vendor.name",
      "limit": 1
    },
    {
      "type": "view-product-link",
      "name": "t:sections.featured_product.blocks.view_product_link.name",
      "limit": 1,
      "settings": [
        {
          "type": "text",
          "id": "text",
          "label": "t:sections.featured_product.blocks.view_product_link.text.label",
          "default": "View full details"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "presets": [
    {
      "name": "t:sections.featured_product.presets.featured_product.name",
      "category": "t:sections.featured_product.presets.featured_product.category",
      "blocks": [
        {
          "type": "title"
        },
        {
          "type": "price"
        },
        {
          "type": "view-product-link"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}

{% endschema %}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is just styling issue. You can customize that text link to be like a button using some CSS codes in your original section template file.

just for an example;

```css
.btn_viewWallGuide {
  padding: 30px 70px;
  background-color: #F04F37;
  border-radius: 6px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 28px;
  font-family: system-ui;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<a class="btn_viewWallGuide" href="{{ section.settings.your_schema_link_id }}">View Wall Guide</a>
```